# Spring XD processor module classloader issue: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring, classloader, spring-xd

I have a problem with Spring XD processor module class loading and wonder how to solve it:

### Background Information

I have a Spring XD processor module that doesn't find some classes when running in the Spring XD container. I got class loading issues with jaxb xml conversion and xstream xml conversion as the classloader couldn't find the classes for converting the xml. The jaxb classes where in another jar file. The xstream classes where in the same (the module's) jar file. The issue can be reproduced easily without any jaxb/xstream code (see below).

### Issue

As soon as the processor module code below gets executed in the Spring XD container the classloader can't find any classes from the module's jar (I changed the package names for this post. Foo is in the same package in the same jar file. There are no external dependencies.):

```
// This is a spring xd processor
public class TestTransformer {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  public String process(String input) {

    try {
      Class clazz = Class.forName("some.package.Foo", false, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
      logger.info("Class: {}", clazz.toString()); // works in test
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // happens when deployed to spring-xd container
      logger.error(e.toString(), e);
      throw new RuntimeException(e.toString(), e);
    }
    return input;

  }
}
```

This code works in tests (Unit tests and Spring XD integration test) but fails when deployed as a module to Spring XD (singlenode). Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: some.package.Foo
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
at some.package.TestTransformer.process(TestTransformer.java:13)
... 88 more
```

I verified the behaviour with Spring XD 1.2.0 and 1.2.1. It might be worth to note that the processor module runs without any class loading issues when using reactor streams.

### Question

What am I doing wrong and how could I solve the issue?

Comment: Are you saying that some.package.Foo is in a separate jar file, e.g., foo.jar and foo.jar is on your module's classpath? i.e., declared as a dependency and lib/foo.jar is contained in your module uberjar?  If your problem is actually related to a jaxb, or xstream class, that's a different issue.

Comment: No, all classes in this example are in the same jar file in the same package. It is not related to jaxb or xstream as I removed all these dependencies by creating the example above to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the Transformer class is referenced by a spring-integration-core class that is loaded by the main XD class loader (parent of the module class loader). So it doesn't see any classes in the module jar. I have created https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3472. Meanwhile, the work around is to put those classes in a separate jar and install the jar in xd/lib.

Comment: I did not verify your solution but I thank you for looking into it, I think you are right. I solved the issue by using a processor with a reactor stream. There classloading works as expected.